# Как поставить условие если папка не содержит файлов?

Tags: java

Добрый день, получаю список файлов из папки

```
File folder = new File("D://Photo_and_Video//");// доступ к папке с файлами
            System.out.println(folder.listFiles());
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();// получаем список файлов
            for (File f : listOfFiles) {

   if(fileName.equals(f.getName())){
         какой то код
    }
  }
```

и соответственно проверяю на совпадение имён, но тут возник вопрос а как задать условие, делать что то если папка не содержит файлов то есть folder.listFiles() ничего не возвращает ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(listOfFiles.length > 0) {
    for(File f : listOfFiles) {
        ...
    }
}
else {
    System.out.println("Пустая папка");
}
```